# smooth horizontal scroll like k2.pl

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to build a website with a horizontal scroll like this website k2.pl

Desc

i have made this code so far jquery animate and scroll to

```
// i am getting y and x axis and moving the whole page agains it
$('.scroll').animate( { scrollLeft: '+='+newScroll }
```

but what i made is that my script gets page X axis of website and move againts it but what i want is that when i hover on an element on the site it should scroll to the center like on this site k2.pl

can you guys suggest me some jquery plugin or that tell me how can improve it

Comment: Am working on a solution for you amrpixel. Sit tight!

Comment: @ᴊᴏɴᴀᴛʜᴀɴʙʀᴏᴏᴋs really thanks i would appreciate that :)

Answer (score 2):

If you check the website and move the mouse, you'll see that the element that you hover on doesn't really go to the center, the movement of the scroll is associated to the horizontal movement of the mouse and has nothing to do with hovering over the different list elements.

The idea is simple:

- Have a container that occupies the whole width of the window and that has a `overflow:hidden`.
- Inside that container have a second container with the same width as the list of elements.
- Inside that container have a list of elements (or a series of inline elements) that occupy more than the width of the window.
- When the mouse moves over the container, calculate the position of the mouse within the window, and scroll the container horizontally accordingly.

A basic version of it would be like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".scroll").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    
    var ww = $(window).width();       // window width
    var uw = $(".scroll ul").width(); // ul width
    var mp = e.clientX;               // mouse position
    var ms = uw - ww;                 // max scroll
    var sc = - ms * mp / ww;          // amount to be scrolled

    $(".scroll > div").stop().animate({ left: sc +"px" }, 600, "easeOutCirc");
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
html, body { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}

div.scroll {
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  position:relative;
}

div.scroll > div {
  width:1400px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

div.scroll > div > ul {
  width:1400px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

div.scroll > div > ul > li {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height:400px;
  opacity:0.7;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}

div.scroll > div > ul > li:hover {
  opacity:1;
  background:#6699cc;
}

div.scroll > div > ul > li:hover > span {
  color:white;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroll">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><span>AAA</span></li>
      <li><span>BBB</span></li>
      <li><span>CCC</span></li>
      <li><span>DDD</span></li>
      <li><span>EEE</span></li>
      <li><span>FFF</span></li>
      <li><span>GGG</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note: the code above may not work if the width of the window is larger than 1400px)

If you check the source code for k2.pl you'll see that they are using jQuery, jQuery UI, and [Ariel Flesler's scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html). You can see the code that controls the scrolling (in a different way to what I explained above) in the script.min.js file (search for `mousemove.sapp`).

Comment: well thanks i really appreciate this snippets that was exaclty what i was looking for but i tried to implement your solution but it my website was doing weird suff

my html structure is like this 


<div >
<ul   >
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
</div>

but i was not able to implement on this then can you please help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here's my working solution. Alvaro's is great, but it uses the jQuery `animate` function which is a big no-no (it's about 10x slower than CSS transitions / the GSAP JavaScript animation library, for example), so I thought you might benefit from another implementation.

I personally like GSAP, which is super easy to pick up; that's why I've used it here. The rest is in native JS so you don't need all that library bloat:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName("tile");
var tileWidth = tiles[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
var containingWidth = tileWidth * tiles.length;

wrapper.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
  var pos = (e.clientX / (wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width)) * containingWidth - (tileWidth / 1.5);
  TweenLite.to(wrapper, 1, { scrollLeft: pos, ease: Circ.easeOut })
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.tile:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div style="background: #6d8745" class="tile"></div>
  <div style="background: #aa715a" class="tile"></div>
  <div style="background: #a25fe3" class="tile"></div>
  <div style="background: #8e84f5" class="tile"></div>
  <div style="background: #259a5c" class="tile"></div>
  <div style="background: #d5b67a" class="tile"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

The principles are essentially the same as Alvaro's. What you have to understand is that the width of the viewport will be a certain percentage of the width of the div / element which contains all of the "tiles" so, taking this into consideration, you have to calculate how to make them map at a 1:1 ratio. That calculation is represented by this line of code (the subtraction at the end is an offset):

```
var pos = (e.clientX / (wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width)) * containingWidth - (tileWidth / 1.5);
```

Hope this helps!

[Original codepen](http://codepen.io/omgtoblerone/pen/jWNEGY?editors=101)

Comment: well thanks it really worked for me i really appreciate that. just one last this can you modify your example for this snippit

`<div > <ul > <li> <li> <li> <li> </ul> </div>`